# Update text value according to Dynamic Form Control Changes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have dynamically generated form controls using FormArray.each those control have associated text value inside `<p>`.when the relevant from control change I want to update that associated  `<p>` value accordingly.how can I achieve that.

In My TS File

```
this.fb.group({guestTemps: this.fb.array([])}) 

onInit():void{
    this.generateFields(this.dataArray)
}

generateFields(array:Array<any>){
  let ref =this.tempInputForm.get('guestTemps') as FormArray;
  array.forEach(items => {ref.push(this.createField())})
}

createField(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      guestId:[""],
      temp:["",Validators.required],
    })
 }
```

My template

```
   <div [formGroup]="tempInputForm">
        <div class="mb-5" *ngFor="let felids of temperatureFelids.controls; let i = index" 
             formArrayName="guestTemps">
                <div [formGroupName]="i">
                    <label for="guesName" class="label-text" formControlName="guestId"> Guest Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text"  id="guesName+{{i}}" formControlName="temp" />
                </div>
                 //i want update the text here when the form contro changes
                <p  class="temperature-indi-msg">i want update the text here</p>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're iterating over a list of FormControls, you can simply access the value of the control in order to conditionally display content:

```html
<div [formGroup]="tempInputForm">
    <div class="mb-5" 
         *ngFor="let felids of temperatureFelids.controls; let i = index" 
         formArrayName="guestTemps">
         <div [formGroupName]="i">
             <label for="guesName" class="label-text" formControlName="guestId"> Guest Last Name</label>
                 <input type="text"  id="guesName+{{i}}" formControlName="temp" />
         </div>
         // Access the value of the FormControl to modify the contents of the <p> tag
         <p  class="temperature-indi-msg">{{felids.value ? 'truthy value' : 'falsey value'}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```